# How to do a query in Yii with multiple primary key values

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

So I have a simple language model whose database structure looks something like this:

```
id | language
_____________

1  | english
2  | japanese
3  | russian
4  | german
5  | thai
```

Say I have a list of comma separated values for languages that an object has ( i.e. 1,4,5). How would I do a database query using Yii and return (1,4,5) into an array with (english, german, thai)?

Answer (score 3):

[addInCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) should suit you, something like:

```
$pkArray = array(1,4,5);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition('id',$pkArray);

$models = Languages::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

**[EDIT]**

Or, as @jborch / @Paystey suggest below, for a primary key lookup you could use [findAllByPk()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByPk-detail) like so:

```
$pkArray = array(1,4,5);

$models = Language::model()->findAllByPk($pkArray);
```

**[/EDIT]**

Should return an array of active record models, so you could cycle through like so:

```
foreach(array_keys($models) as $key)
{
    echo '<p>Language: '.$models[$key]->name.'</p>';
}
```

Or if you needed an array of names,

```
CHtml::listData($models,'id','name');
```

Would give you an array like so:

```
array(
    1 => 'english',
    4 => 'german',
    5 => 'thai'
)
```

Comment: Or just `Language::model()->findByPk(array(1,4,5));`

Comment: lol yes, why didn't I think of that, findAllByPk() will be perfect for your lookup, my method above still good for non Pk lookups too ;)